# When implementing the FAST protocol (from FIX) when should I reset the template parser?

Tags: java, quickfix, fix-protocol

I am implementing my own FAST handler/parser and some templates relies on a previous value of a field, like the *copy* operation that says: *If not present, use the last/previous value received.*

Every field has a reset method that clears the previous value of the field.

According to this link: http://jettekfix.com/node/44

You should reset the template after you process every message. Now that's a contradiction, in other words, how am I going to use the previous value of a field if I am resetting it after every message???

I must be missing something here. When should I reset the template parser?

Comment: I haven't seen the code, but I would assume the reset would happen `If not present, use the last/previous value received` after you have taken care of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a contradiction if you take into account FAST sequences (i.e. FIX repeating groups). Most exchanges will reset the templates on each messages sent so a participant can join at any point. But inside the same FAST message, fields will be repeated inside a FAST sequence and that's when operations like *copy* come into play.

Answer (score 1):

the link http://jettekfix.com/node/44 doesn't say you should reset the dictionary before processing each FAST message, but it does say you should reset it before processing each TCP/UDP packets, or after connection established. For example some exchange protocol have one UDP packet with multiple FAST messages bundled, you should not reset the dictionary in between.